# About Folland prop 2.7

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Proposition 2.7 in Folland emphasizes that $f: X\rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$. Does the same conclusion hold for $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Proposition 2.7 Suppose $f_n:X\rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable, $\forall n$, then $\sup f_n$, $\inf f_n$, $\limsup f_n$, $\liminf f_n$ are all measurable.

Comment: It would be nice to include the actual proposition in the question text. Keeping things self-contained is always desirable.

Comment: @EuYu Thanks, it is a good reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proposition holds as long as it's making statements about $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions.  For example, say that $f_1$ is the constant function $1$, $f_2$ is the constant function $2$, et cetera... well, these are all measurable, so Proposition 2.7 says that their supremum is measurable.

But their supremum is the constant function $f(x) = \infty$!  If you're banning infinity completely, then you have to make exceptions for cases like this.  For the proposition to be true, you have to modify it to look like this: "If blah only takes real values, then blah is measurable."

On the other hand, if you're okay with getting infinities out as long as you put $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions in, then what you're asking about is just a special case of the same proposition.

Is this reasonably clear?

Comment: The special case argument helps me out. Thanks!

Comment: @Felix You're very welcome; glad to hear it was helpful.  Trying out simple special cases is one of the most powerful and underrated tools in all of mathematics.